# MSBuild. Execution of second target

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, target

I use code like this:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<UsingTask TaskName="MSBuildTasks.Tasks.XmlReader" AssemblyFile="Tasks/MSBuildTasks.dll"/>
  <Target Name="Start">
    <CallTarget  Targets="test1"/>
    <CallTarget  Targets="test2"/>
  </Target>
  <Target Name="test1">
    <Message Text="text1"/>
  </Target>
  <Target Name="test2" DependsOnTargets="test1;"> //I tried with and without semicolon
    <Message Text="text2"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

My output works fine. But if I delete "Start" target. Output shows the message only form first target. 
If it is not supposed to work in that way what for the DependsOnTargets attribute?
What is "True" way to execute multiple targets?
MsBuild 4.0, VS 2010 CMD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you call the script, i.e. the `/targets:` option?

I'm guessing since you don't specify `DefaultTargets` or `InitialTargets` MSBuild by default executes the first target available and since it's no longer `Start` but `test1` the `DependsOnTargets` is no longer relevant.